# $\max_x \max_y f(x,y) = \max_y \max_x f(x,y)?$

Tags: optimization

Just come across a question regarding sequential maximization and simultaneous maximization, and I do not recall whether there are any established conditions for the equivalence. Anyone has some idea?

$$\max_x \max_y f(x,y) =\max_y \max_x f(x,y)?$$

Comment: Did you mean both to be $\max$?

Answer (score 5):

> $$\max_x \max_y f(x,y) =\max_y \max_x f(x,y)?$$

Let $(x,y)\in X\times Y$.
$$
f(x,y) \le \max_x f(x,y)
\le \max_y \max_x f(x,y);$$as this is true for every $y\in Y$,
$$
\max_y f(x,y) =\max_y \max_x f(x,y);
$$and as this is true for every $x\in X$:
$$\max_x \max_y f(x,y) \le \max_y \max_x f(x,y).$$

Now use the symetry to get
the conclusion.

Comment: Sorry oft the delayed comment. Is it possible to elaborate a little more? Which symmetry should be used to get $\max_x \max_y f(x,y) =\max_y \max_x f(x,y)$.

Comment: I believe the is a mistake (or typo?): $\max_y f(x,y) \neq \max_y \max_x f(x,y)$ (the lhs is a function of $x$ (hence not constant in principle) while the rhs is a fixed number)